# ¿Qué es una función universal?

Tags: python, numpy

Soy totalmente nuevo en programación y estoy practicando. En un ejercicio me pide desarrollar una función universal, me podrían ayudar diciendome que es una función universal por favor.

Comment: Y te dan más detalles sobre la definición de una función universal?

Answer (score 1):

[Según la documentación de NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html)

> A universal function (or [*ufunc*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) for short) is a function that operates on [`ndarrays`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray) in an element-by-element fashion, supporting [*array broadcasting*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-broadcasting), [*type casting*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-casting), and several other standard features. That is, a ufunc is a “*vectorized*” wrapper for a function that takes a fixed number of scalar inputs and produces a fixed number of scalar outputs.
>
> In Numpy, universal functions are instances of the `numpy.ufunc` class. Many of the built-in functions are implemented in compiled C code, but `ufunc` instances can also be produced using the [`frompyfunc`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc) factory function.

Traducción:

> Una función universal (abreviado [*ufunc*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html)) es una función que opera en [`ndarrays`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray) elemento por elemento, soportando [*array broadcasting*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-broadcasting), [*conversión de tipos*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-casting), y varias otras características estándar. Es decir, un ufunc es un wrapper “*vectorizado*” de una función que toma un número fijo de entradas escalares y produce un número fijo de salidas escalares.
>
> En Numpy, las funciones universales son instancias de la clase `numpy.ufunc`. Muchas de las funciones disponibles son implementadas en código C compilado, pero instancias `ufunc` también pueden ser producidas usando la factory function  [`frompyfunc`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc).

Comment: Pero, se referirá a Numpy específicamente? =0